# Mean time spent in a state in a CT Markov Chain

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I consider a continuous-time homogenous Markov chain:
with discrete state $X$ taking values in $\mathcal{F}=\{1,\cdots,N\}$  with the transition rates satisfying:
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
Pr\{X(t+h)=j\lvert X(t)=i\}=\lambda_{ij}h+o(h),\\
Pr\{X(t+h)=i\lvert X(t)=i\}=1-\lambda_{ii}h+o(h)
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
where $\lambda_{ii}=\sum_{i\neq j}\lambda_{ij}$.

Transition Probabilities are defined as $P_{ij}(t)=Pr\{X(t)=j\,|\,X(0)=i\}, t\geq 0$. These probabilities are obtained by solving the Kolmogorov forward equation given as:

$
\dot{P}_{ij}=-\lambda_{ii}P_{ij}(t)+\sum_{y\neq j}P_{iy}(t)\lambda_{yj}$

Now, probability of being at state $j$ denoted by $\pi_j(t)$ is given by:
\begin{equation}
\pi_j(t)=Pr\{X(t)=j\}=\sum_i Pr\{X(t)=j\,|\,X(0)=i\}Pr\{X(0)=i\}=\sum_iP_{ij}Pr\{X(0)=i\}
\end{equation}
Using the above equation and kolmogorov forward equation, it is concluded that:
\begin{equation}
\dot{\pi}_j=-\lambda_{jj}\pi_j+\sum_{y\neq j}\pi_{y}\lambda_{yj},
\end{equation}
or in the matrix form:
\begin{equation}
\dot{\pi}(t)=A\pi(t)
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
A_{ij}=\begin{cases} -\lambda_{ii}~\text{if}~i=j\\
\lambda_{ji}~\text{if}~i\neq j
\end{cases}.
\end{equation}
I am interested in finding the mean-time that it  spent in a state i?

My attempt:
Suppose $X(0)=i$
Let us denote the time that is spent in $i$ by $T_i$. For some $s,t\geq 0$, we have:
\begin{equation}
Pr\{T_i\geq s+t|T_i> s\}=Pr(T_i> t)
\end{equation}
I guess that I need to find the $Pr\{T_i\leq t\}$ and then

$E(T_i)=\int_0^\infty t\frac{d}{dt}Pr\{T_i\leq t\}dt $.

Comment: By "the mean time spent in $i$", do you mean the mean time spent in $i$ before first leaving $i$ when starting at $i$? Because this time is exponentially distributed with parameter $\lambda_{ii}$ hence its mean is just $1/\lambda_{ii}$ (as every textbook explains).

Comment: I mean the expected value of the total time spent in state $i$.

Comment: Counting the time spent in $i$ after leaving it and coming back to it one or several times? Then in your context this time is (almost surely) identically infinite, as is its expectation.

Comment: Can we impose any condition on the chain so that the time is finite?

Comment: Yes, transience (in the finite case, this would be an absorbing state).

Comment: Ok, what if I only consider  the time interval $I=[0,T_M]$ and then I am interested in the average time that is spent in state $i$ during the interval $I$?

Comment: Then this proportion of time converges to $\pi_i$ when $T_M\to\infty$, assuming the chain is what is called *irreducible*. (All this is basic Markov chains stuff, you know?)